# how to combine two mutable arrays?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone application in which i am trying to add two mutable arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *dataArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *news = [dict objectForKey:@"news"];
NSDictionary *deals = [dict objectForKey:@"deals"];
NSLog(@"%@", [news classForCoder]);
NSLog(@"%@", news);

for (NSDictionary *key in news)
{ 
    if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        [dataArray addObject:key];      
    }
}

for (NSDictionary *key in deals)
{
    if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        [dataArray1 addObject:key];        
    }
}

self.newssarray = dataArray;
[self.mTableView reloadData];
```

Here I want to add the two arrays 'dataArray' and 'dataArray2' to be combined into one array (`self.newsarray`). Can anybody help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

NSMutable array has all of NSArray's methods, including one for creating a new array by adding another array to itself:

```
self.newsarray = [[dataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dataArray1] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,But it is giving me a warning incompatable pointer types from nsmutable array to nsarray?

Comment: I assume you mean that the @property is expects to be mutable; answer modified.

Comment: `self.newsarray = [[dataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dataArray1] mutableCopy];` happy now....

Comment: Instead of answer or commenting I should have edited your answer...
sorry my bad...

Comment: Good call; SO has thought of everything ;-)

Comment: One thing to watch out for with this method is that if dataArray is nil you'll end up with the new array being nil even if dataArray1 isn't nil or empty.

Comment: @MarkBridges fantastic observation. In the original question, the code to create the dataArray1 is in the same block, so this is an extremely unlikely scenario. In general, however, handling that case would be the right thing to do with this code. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If your property is NSMutableArray :

```
self.newsarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dataArray1]];
```

If it is NSArray :

```
self.newsarray = [dataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dataArray1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 . Easy ans simple way

```
let arrayFind = NSMutableArray()
let arrayNotFind = NSMutableArray()

let arrPicOne = arrayFind as! [Any]
let arrPicTwo = arrayNotFind as! [Any]

let tempResult = arrPicOne + arrPicTwo

let arrResult = NSMutableArray(array: tempResult)
```